# My personalized css affects uikit.css work on nav cursor

Tags: html, css, nav, getuikit

I have an issue with with the css in Uikit and I can't figure out.
I have a Nav section and when I hover on list items it doesn't change the cursor pointer. I have set a personalized css file named custom.css. If I remove that from code, it works. Again, if i out the code in a new html file without my css it works.
I can't solve my issue in any way.

Here below the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>CVING</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="navigation" class="uk-width-1-1">
            <!-- Navigation Large Medium Devices -->
            <nav class="uk-navbar">
                <div id="brand" class="uk-navbar-brand">
                   <a href="#"><img src="images/cving_neg.png" alt="CV Ing Interview Platform"></a>
                </div>
                <ul id="menu" class="uk-navbar-nav uk-navbar-flip uk-grid-small">
                    <li><a id="radar" href=""></a></li>
                    <li class="uk-active"><a id="cv" href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a id="career" href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a id="personalitytest" href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a id="settings" href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a id="avatar" href=""></a></li>
                </ul>


            </nav>

        </div> <!-- Fine Navigation -->

        <div id="content">
            <div id="wrap-cv" class="uk-container-center uk-width-1-2 uk-grid-small">
                <div id="menu-cv" class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-border-rounded uk-contrast">

                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon uk-width-1-1" data-uk-nav>
                        <li class="uk-active"><a href="">Active</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item</a></li>

                        <li class="uk-parent">
                            <a href="#">Parent</a>
                            <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                                <li><a href="">Sub item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Sub item</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="">Sub item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Sub item</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="uk-parent">
                            <a href="#">Parent</a>
                            <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                                <li><a href="">Sub item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Sub item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

an here my css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* Navigation */

#navigation {
    background-color: #0080D4;
    height: auto;
}

#navigation nav {
    background-color: #0080D4;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 46px;
}

ul#menu {
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: 4px
}

ul#menu li {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

ul#menu li.uk-active a, ul#menu li.uk-active a img{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}

#radar {
    background: url("../images/radar-b.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.uk-active #radar {
    background: url("../images/radar-w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#cv {
    background: url("../images/cv-b.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.uk-active #cv {
    background: url("../images/cv-w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#career {
    background: url("../images/career-b.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.uk-active #career {
    background: url("../images/career-w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#personalitytest {
    background: url("../images/personalitytest-b.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.uk-active #personalitytest {
    background: url("../images/personalitytest-w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#settings {
    background: url("../images/settings-b.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.uk-active #settings {
    background: url("../images/settings-w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#avatar {
    background: url("../images/user_avatar_website.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

ul#menu li:hover a {

    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}

ul#menu li:last-child:hover a {
    border-radius: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*  Content */

#content {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(13, 69, 133, 0.8), rgba(13, 69, 133, 0.8) ), url("../images/background.jpg") no-repeat center 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

div#wrap-cv {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu-cv {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0d4585;

}

div#menu-cv ul {padding-top: 5px;}

/*div#menu-cv ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
}*/

/* Content Header with Shape Effect */

#header-cv {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0D4585;
    padding: 0 20px 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3a679c;
    right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 60%;


}

#header-cv:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    border: 20px solid #0D4585;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

#header-cv:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 40%;
    border: 20px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #0D4585;
    border-right-width: 100px;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

#header-cv h6 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;

}

/* End Content Header with Shape Effect */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove position from #content ID
try this

```css
#content {
/*    position: relative; */
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(13, 69, 133, 0.8), rgba(13, 69, 133, 0.8) ), url("../images/background.jpg") no-repeat center 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```